# Button moves up when I launch app on Nexus4 ADV

Tags: android, eclipse, button, layer

I made my android app, a background, and some buttons. I run the app on my Galaxy S Device, and it's ok as I designed the buttons are where I put them. When I start the same app on virtual device Nexus4, the buttons always move a little up.

What is the cause? What can I do, so on all devices buttons to stay on the same place?

Comment: take a look at this http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As android is running on multiple devices with multiple screen with different resolutions, here is how to support them:  [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Basically we have following screens resolution:

```
xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp
large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp
normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp
small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp
```

[image]

to support them all, in **Res** folder we have to create folders depending what screens we want to support.

```
layout-xlarge
layout-large
layout-normal
layout-small
```

after, copy the your final  layout_file.xml to all of them, open it in Graphical mode, and rearrange the buttons to look good on the screen. Depending on the resolution screen android will choose layout which is closer to device resolution . Just test it on different devices, or virtual devices to make sure it looks good.

Answer (score 0):

the problem might be that you may use your own defined sizes for buttons like

android:layout_width="80dp"
android:layout_height="40dp"

and layout_marginTop,Left,Rigth attributes

because supplying our own values varies for different screen orientations from small screen mobiles to large screen tablets

best culture the habits of using wrap_content,fill_parent,match_parent
 and layout_weightsum for Linear layouts

Comment: Yes, my height is 55 dp, if i am setting as wrap, my button height is very streched :(